# How to create a multi-type vector in c++

Tags: c++, cmake, android-ndk

I need to create a vector that will accept multiple types of data. The vector will be converted into a string and hashed with SHA1. I tried creating a `vector<boost::any>` and creating a string with `std::string(v.begin(), v.end())`, but that results in...

```
/Users/yash/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/c++/v1/string:2065:22: error: no matching member function for call to 'assign'
traits_type::assign(*__p, *__first);
~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
              /Users/yash/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/c++/v1/string:2074:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> >::__init<std::__ndk1::__wrap_iter<boost::any *> >' requested here
__init(__first, __last);
^
/Users/yash/BuildBox/GDBIAG15 android/EzNotes/app/src/main/cpp/Obfuscator.cpp:21:30: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> >::basic_string<std::__ndk1::__wrap_iter<boost::any *>, void>' requested here
salt = hashSaltUsingSHA1(std::string(v.begin(), v.end()));
^
/Users/yash/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/c++/v1/__string:208:10: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'boost::any' to 'const std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>::char_type' (aka 'const char') for 2nd argument
void assign(char_type& __c1, const char_type& __c2) _NOEXCEPT {__c1 = __c2;}
^
/Users/yash/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/c++/v1/__string:227:30: note: candidate function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
static inline char_type* assign(char_type* __s, size_t __n, char_type __a) _NOEXCEPT
^
1 error generated.
[2/3] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/native-lib.cpp.o
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

                                 * Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Edit: A clearer definition of what I am trying to do. Get the raw data of multiple complex objects in the form of one string, and hash with SHA1

Comment: `std::string` doesn't know how to convert `boost::any` to character data. Most of the time, trying to use an `any` type for type punning doesn't work because it will be impossible to recover the object's original type.  You need to include a mechanism for that yourself, which is not an easy thing to do.

Comment: If "multiple types of data" means "classes derived from a common base, with a virtual interface" then I think it should be easy enough. If not, I can't see how to do it.

Comment: _I need to create a vector that will accept multiple types of data_ assuming you know which types, `std::variant` may be a better idea. It may not solve your specific issue immediately, but it may make things a bit easier.

Comment: Have you tried casting everything as a void* and keeping a separate vector to recover the types (or maybe a std::pair or small struct that has a field for the type and a field for the data as a void*)?

Comment: Do you need to keep all the objects you read in?  Hash functions and SHA1 can be designed as additive (adding more data).  You don't need to store all of the objects, one instance of each is enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the output of the compiler (they are verbose but readable if you take the time) the constructor of `std::string` expects some char_type pointer. You can't directly convert a `boost::any` into a char.

If you want to convert your vector into a string, you have to use an intermidiate function to convert the data inside your `boost::any` object into a char or a string and then concatenate them into one single string.

You could try something like that:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost stuff>

struct foo { };

bool is_string(boost::any *any) {
    return any_cast<std::string *>(any) != nullptr;
}

bool is_foo(boost::any *any) {
    return any_cast<foo *>(any) != nullptr;
}

std::string foo_to_string(const foo& f) {
    ....
}

std::string any_to_string(boost::any& any) {
    if (is_string(&any))
        return any_cast<std::string>(any);
    else if(is_foo(&any))
        return foo_to_string(any_cast<foo>(any));
    else
        return "";
}

int main() {
    std::vector<boost::any> objects;
    std::string result;
    
    // you can refactor that with std::accumulate
    for (const auto& object: objects) {
         result += any_to_string(foo);
    }

    std::cout << result << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

I've never used `boost::any` before so this might not work out of the box but from what I understand from the documentation you have the general idea of how you can implement it.

Finally, it's possible that you don't need `boost::any`. You can often find more type safe solution if you rethink your implementation. But without more details, I can't give you any hints.